# How to call Accounts.createUser outside of server methods

Tags: meteor

I need to create new user when I recived message from rabbitmq. But Accounts.createUser doesn't work outside methods even if I wrap it with Meteor.bindEnvironment. But for example IronRouter works well when I call createUser. How I can create new users outside of Meteor methods or client?

```
var newUserCreate = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(msg){
                                              var email, username = msg.data.email;
                                              var password = msg.data.password;
                                              Accounts.createUser({username: username, email: email, password: password});
                                            }, function(e){throw e;})
```

And just call newUserCreate(msg)

Comment: How do you call it currently from the queue (could you post the Meteor code?) and what happens?

Comment: Nothing is happens, no new records in users collection, but if I try console.log(this) I see all methods and collections, I don't know why it doesn't work as usually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
var a, b = 42;
```

Then `b` is equal to `42`, but `a` stays `undefined`. My guess is that the method fails because you pass `email: undefined` in params. So try to rewrite it and see what happens:

```
var newUserCreate = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(msg) {
    var email = msg.data.email;
    var username = msg.data.email;
    var password = msg.data.password;
    var result = Accounts.createUser({username: username, email: email, password: password});
    console.log("RESULT", result);
}, function(e){
    throw e;
});
```

Comment: Oh, many thx that's because I write on 2 languages python and javascript, and damn deadlines them killing me ))

Answer (score 1):

It should 'just work'. Remember don't pass a callback on the server it wont fire. You have to instead look for what it returns. Fibers will make sure meteor waits until the user is created before the next statement is run. What is returned is the new user's `_id`.

e.g

```
var result = Account.createUser(params);
```

Comment: It works well inside Meteor.methods, but outside them it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you running it in a Fiber?